# Is it possible to play pre-recorded voice for an existing annotation skmaps android?

Tags: android, navigation, skmaps

Is it possible to play a pre-recorded voice for an existing annotation right when the user navigation icon crosses the annotation in skmaps? I am using 2.5.1 android

Answer (score 1):

This is not something connected to the SDK itself but an app level integration.

You could set up a "watch" for that annotation using the POI tracking functionality (see http://sdkblog.skobbler.com/detecting-tracking-pois-in-your-way/) and you'll receive a notification once you arrive in the vicinity of that annotation, at which time you can play your advice.